# How do I detect the same anchor link clicked multiple times on the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a question for you guys.

Lets say I have an **internal anchor link on the same page** as in http://jquery.com/#myAnchor

Now if I click on the anchor, then the url will be http://jquery.com/#myAnchor

And if I click on the anchor again, the url will again be http://jquery.com/#myAnchor

aka, the url actually does not change .. just the link clicked twice on the page. How do I detect that the internal anchor has been clicked again?
For example

```
<a name="myAnchor"></a>
```

If the above anchor link is on the same page,  then how do I detect this hashChange.

Actually I have function that detects hashChange on a page as in below. but the code fails for this one particular codition

```
 $(window).on('load hashchange', function () {
```

Comment: write a click handler for the anchor

Comment: There is no way to know what part of the page may have the anchor

Comment: then you'll have to find a way to add a click handler

Comment: though your question is full of explaination , but less in codes

Comment: _"There is no way to know what part of the page may have the anchor"_ ? Select parent of clicked element ?

Comment: instead of tracking the url, why not track the click events? 

   var clicked = 0; 
    $("#myAnchor").click(function() {
        clicked++;
    });

Answer (score 1):

use `data-` attributes. When user clicks the anchor link, just increment the data attribute.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.myLink') .click(function(e) {
        e.prevenDefault();
        var count = $(this).attr('data-clicked');
        count = parseInt(count) + 1;
        $(this).attr('data-clicked', count);
    });
});

<a class="myLink" data-clicked="0">Anchor Tag</a>
```

Comment: BTW, if that helped you solving the issue, please accept the answer.

Comment: Check `dta-clicked` in your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use event delegation to track the clicks, something like

```
$(document).on('click', '[href="#myAnchor"]', function(){
//do whatever you want here
});
```

Also named anchors are obsolete, you should be using `id`s instead.

```
<section id="myAnchor">
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add any class when user click on anchor tag . User click again on that ancor tag check hasClass()

Please check Below Jsfiddle  `enter code here`

http://jsfiddle.net/upardhi/2krq8Lsy/

Answer (score 0):

You can check like this also

```js
$(document).on('click', 'a', function() {
  var link = $(this).attr('href'),
    currentLink = window.location.href;
  if (link == currentLink)
    return false;
  else
  //your conditions

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a name="myAnchor" href="http://jquery.com/#myAnchor">Test</a>
```